# Easily using Boost from within CMake without installing Boost (Boost CMake Modularization)

Tags: boost, cmake

It seems there were/are efforts to do this, but most of the resources I've seen so far are either outdated (with dead links) or have little to no information to actually build a small working sample (that, for example relies on boost `program_options` to build an executable).

Also, when using `ExternalProject_Add`, how does one resolve dependencies inside of Boost?

I'm basically looking to use Boost easily from  within CMake with little to no manual configuration.

Comment: I'm working on CMake package [manager](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter). To add boost to your project you can use `hunter_add_package(Boost COMPONENTS regex filesystem)`. Example: [1](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/blob/master/examples/Boost-ios/CMakeLists.txt), [2](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/blob/master/examples/Boost-filesystem/CMakeLists.txt) Version is unstable, work in progress (:

Comment: @ruslo Your project is really interesting, how do I use it on Windows? Do I have to install your cmake modules into Modules?

Comment: No, you only need to copy one file into your project. See this [repo](https://github.com/hunter-packages/gate). What generator are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows and need to generate Visual Studio solutions at this time. A step-by-step explanation would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Copy one file `HunterGate.cmake` from [this](https://github.com/hunter-packages/gate) project to your local project and include it: `include(HunterGate.cmake)`. Then add command:
`hunter_add_package(Boost COMPONENTS foo bar)`. After this command you can use usual find_package: `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS foo bar)`.

Comment: I recommend you to build project(at least at first time) from command line with option `HUNTER_STATUS_DEBUG=ON`. Because `cmake-gui` not showing download/build/install progress. Also you can specify `HUNTER_ROOT` variable (cmake or environment) to point to directory where hunter project will reside. Contact me by e-mail (you can find it in my commit message) if you have some questions. I'm really interested in feedback right now (:

Comment: @ruslo Sorry for the late follow-up, but I was busy working with other stuff and now it's back to this item. Could you please make this an answer so I can follow up with one question and then accept it as the answer I was looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently (August 2017) Boost libraries do not provide CMake support nor are they build using CMake. Boost has its own build system called b2. In July 2017 the [Boost steering committee announced](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2017/07/237248.php) that all boost libraries should be moved to use CMake. This affects users and developers, i.e., CMake will be used internally to build the libraries and externally it will provide CMake config files.

As the build system question triggered heated discussions in the past years and there are strong feeling from part of the community against b2 and CMake, the outcome of this decision is unclear (first release with CMake, will all old libraries support CMake, even a split of the Boost community).

### Original Answer from 2015

You can consider the effort to introduce CMake as a first-class citizen to boost as dead. See the [mailing list thread about the topic](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2015/11/226557.php).

If you don't want to use third party tools like hunter's package manager, check the most current verion of the boost library you want to use. Maybe you are lucky and it provides some CMakeLists.txt files you can use.

Answer (score 5):

Try [Hunter](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter) package manager:

```
hunter_add_package(Boost COMPONENTS regex system filesystem)
find_package(Boost CONFIG REQUIRED regex system filesystem)
target_link_libraries(foo PUBLIC Boost::regex Boost::system Boost::filesystem)
```

*Note that usage of imported Boost targets is importand for relocatable packages*

#### Wiki

- [Boost package](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/wiki/pkg.boost)
- [Relocation notes](https://github.com/ruslo/hunter/wiki/example.find_package.config#relocation-challenge)

#### Examples

- [Small](https://github.com/forexample/hunter-simple)
- [Big](https://github.com/ruslo/weather)

Answer (score 0):

The most recent work on 'a boost which uses CMake and makes boost use ideal for CMake users' is here:

https://github.com/boost-cmake/boost-cmake

It requires cmake master branch (until CMake 3.0.0 is released soon) and I haven't attempted to build it in a while. Someone in the boost community would have to push forward with transitioning boost to CMake. The boost community might still be busy with transitioning to git.

Comment: Hi Stephen! This project looks very nice, but all links to boost cmake modularization status is marked as `out-of-date` or `deprecated` and [ryppl](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ryppl-dev) mailing list's last messages is about tools which intent to replace ryppl (: I have some questions about this project, where should I ask them? BTW my project will work fine with both `b2` and `cmake` boost build system (not simultaneously of course)

Comment: Try asking your questions on the boost developers mailing list http://lists.boost.org/mailman/listinfo.cgi/boost